# Table not fitting in page

Tags: tables

I have a long and wide table (9 columns, 67 rows).
For the moment I have tried to use the lscape package to have it presented horizontally. The problem is that it's still too long and too wide, so that many rows and the last column don't fit into the page.

I am familiar with the longtable package and have tried to use it, but it still doesn't fit (neither horizontally nor vertically).

Does anybody have any ideas why this may be happening? Is resizing the font the only thing I can do?

I found some helpful posts but I am still wondering what's best in my case.

I report a fraction of the code in case it's needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lscape} 

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{table}[H]

  \sisetup{

    input-digits = ()-01234567890,

    input-open-uncertainty = ,

    input-close-uncertainty = ,

    table-align-text-post = false,

detect-all
  }
  \centering

  \begin{longtable}{lccccccccc}

\label{tab:panel_main} \\ \hline
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 4} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 7} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 8} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Model 9} \\
    \midrule

    year 1958 & 1.314* & -     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.363*} & -     & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.558**} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.345} & -     & -     & - \\
   
 year 1959 & 0.209 & -     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.0816} & -     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.625} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.148} & -     & -     & - \\
         \bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you complete your code with document class, \begin{document} and \end{document} up to a compilable MWE? And what is the idea of the alignment to the left or to the right in the cells? Is it a logical choice?

Comment: May be also add a screenshot?

Comment: Nesting the `longtable` environment inside of a `table` does not make sense as it prevents page breaking. Remove the `table` environment. Also, your example code is not compilable, as at least the `booktabs` package is missing.

Comment: You mention landscape orientation and the `longtable` package. You could combine both.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy \begin{document}. How can I repost the code?

Comment: The table environment was not my idea. They suggested it to me when I was trying to change the alignment of the digits so that I could align the decimal markers. I don't know if there is another way to use \sisetup that doesn't involve creating a table environment.

Comment: I tried to combine longtable with the landscape orientation, but the table is still too big

Comment: I'm sorry but what's the problem with the alignment? I cannot see it (I'm not saying that there is no mistake, just that I don't understand where)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Placing a `longtable` in a `table` environment is wrong, because `table` cannot be broken across pages.

My impression is that you have a standard table. Here's some advice to get a better and smaller one.

Never repeat information: you can simply group the model columns and assign numbers to them. Similarly, repeating “year” can be avoided using a header.

With `siunitx`, aligning figures is much easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\sisetup{table-align-text-after = false}

\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 l
 S[table-format=1.3{*}]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 S[table-format=1.4{*}]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 S[table-format=-1.3{**}]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 @{}
}

\toprule
Year & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Model} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-10}
& {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} \\
\midrule

1958 & 1.314* & {--} & 1.363* & {--} & 1.558** & 1.345 & {--} & {--} & {--} \\

1959 & 0.209 & {--}  & 0.0816 & {--} & -0.625 & 0.148 & {--}  & {--} & {--} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l@{}}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l@{}}{*** $p<0.01$, ** $p<0.05$, * $p<0.1$} \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the settings of the columns depending on the actual values you have.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works with `lscape` and `siunitx`. Note that a `longtable` is not a float, so it doesn't have to  be nested in a `table` environment, and it is automatically centred, so `\centering`  is useless. I added various improvements and simplifications of code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \sisetup{%
    input-digits = ()-01234567890,
    input-signs = -,
    input-open-uncertainty = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    detect-all,
    table-format =-1.4***}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}l*{9}{S}}

\label{tab:panel_main} \\ \hline
    \toprule
    & {Model 1} & {Model 2} & {Model 3} & {Model 4} & {Model 5} & {Model 6} & {Model 7} & {Model 8} & {Model 9} \\
    \midrule
    year 1958 & 1.314* & {$ - $} & 1.363* & {$ - $} & 1.558** & 1.345 & {$ - $} & {$ - $} & {$ - $} \\
 year 1959 & 0.209 & {$ - $} & 0.0816 & {$ - $} & -0.625 & 0.148 & {$ - $}& {$ - $} & {$ - $} \\
         \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{10}{l}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{10}{l}{ *** $p<0.01$, \enspace ** $p<0.05$,\enspace * $p<0.1$}
  \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]